# How to use another script function in squarespace?

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I am trying to use some script in squarespace. those script are perfectly working when I simply run the index.html, but when I try to do the same with squarespace 2 scripts are called and then the third which is supposed to access a function in a script initialised before, the function is said undefined.

```
<squarespace:script src="TemplateData/UnityProgress.js" combo="true" />
<squarespace:script src="Build/UnityLoader.js" combo="true" />
<script> var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/buildForWeb.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});</script>
```

Comment: A couple steps to help you troubleshoot:
1) Set `combo="false"` and try again. Squarespace's script combiner/compressor may have trouble with some scripts. If it still doesn't work, go to #2.
2) Put the scripts in your `/assets` folder instead and load them without `squarespace:script` using a standard `script` element with `src` as `/assets/myscript.js`

Comment: the first didn't work but the second does. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon suggested in his comment:

you can put the scripts in your `/assets` folder instead and load them without `squarespace:script` using a standard `script` element with `src` as `/assets/myscript.js`